# Print all existing doskeys

Tags: windows, alias, doskey

Windows uses [`doskey`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSKEY) to do something like Unix's [`alias`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)). To display all existing Unix aliases I can simply type `alias` with no arguments. However, on Windows, typing `doskey` with no arguments does nothing. How can I display all existing doskeys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all defined macros by using

```
doskey /MACROS
```

Which is listed in the help, which you can view with

```
doskey /?
```